# How I pack a multi-target package with MSBuild 15?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using the new MSBuild 15 distributed with VS2017 RC to compile and pack a multi targeting project.

Restoring: `msbuild /t:restore mysolution.sln` works correctly.

Building: `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release mylibrary.csproj` works correctly and generates:

```
+ bin/Release
  + netstandard1.4
    - mylibrary.dll
  + net452
    - mylibrary.dll
```

But when I am packing: `msbuild /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:IncludeSymbols=true mylibrary.csproj` the structure does not match well with the previous build, looking like:

```
+ bin/Release
  + netstandard1.4
    - mylibrary.pdb
  + net452
    - mylibrary.pdb
  - mylibrary.dll
```

Warnings from the `/t:pack` command show me this was gonna happen, but not sure how to solve it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(73,5): warning : Issue found with package 'MyLibrary'. [D:\XXX\YYY\src\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(73,5): warning : Issue: Assembly not inside a framework folder. D:\XXX\YYY\src\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(73,5): warning : Description: The assembly 'lib\MyLibrary.dll' is placed directly under 'lib' folder. It is recommended that assemblies be placed inside a framework-specific folder.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(73,5): warning : Solution: Move it into a framework-specific folder. If this assembly is targeted for multiple frameworks, ignore this warning.
```

Notes:

I am not using a `*.nuspec` file. Just the new way `*.csproj` files work (https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/msbuild-targets#pack-target)

This is how some of the relevant content of the file look like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <OutputType>library</OutputType>
            <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net452</TargetFrameworks>
            <AssemblyName>MyLibrary</AssemblyName>
            <Authors>XXX</Authors>
            <Description>YYY</Description>
            <PackageId>MyLibrary</PackageId>
            <PackageVersion>1.2.3</PackageVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: _The assembly 'lib\MyLibrary.dll' is placed directly under 'lib' folder. It is recommended that assemblies be placed inside a framework-specific folder._ Did you tried that?

Comment: i use dotnet build /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:IncludeSymbols=true mylibrary.csproj, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I found my way on based on them.

This is what I did: I downloaded the `dotnet` cli tool again and test it from scratch. I realized that the version of the cli tool were the same so I started comparing the files inside.

#### Wrong dotnet cli version

The version that was not working contained the following files:

```
+ dotnet
  + sdk
    + 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
    + 1.0.0-preview2-003131
    + 1.0.0-preview2-003133
    + 1.0.0-preview4-004233
```

Using `dotnet build /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:IncludeSymbols=true mylibrary.csproj` showed the following error:

```
Couldn't find 'project.json' in '/t:pack'
```

#### Good dotnet cli version

The second version I downloaded contained only these:

```
+ dotnet
  + sdk
    + 1.0.0-preview4-004233
```

And executing the command before, it works correctly:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.458.808
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

...
```